# jetpack suddendly stopped working

Tags: plugin-jetpack

Suddendly Jetpack stopped working on my (multisite) blog. I tried to disconnect and reconnect it, but now a timeout message appears:

```
The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site 
https://xmau.com/wp/notiziole [IXR -32300: transport error: 
http_request_failed cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 
10001 milliseconds]
```

Blog is reachable, and I can (manually) add other plugins giving username and password to Wordpress. I changed theme and removed plugins, with no effect. My only doubt is that the server runs a very old version of PHP (5.6.40), but documentation says that it supports from 5.6.20.

What could I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue last year (minus the old php version) and they modified some firewall or something.  Try contacting jetpack support: https://jetpack.com/contact-suppoot